# QBO3 How to get the PersonID on a form?

Tags: javascript, xslt

I am working on a Custom Form in a QBO3 system and will be calling some Javascript to save data from the form into the Payment table as a row.  When I do this there are two fields that require a PersonID: the CreatedPersonID and UpdatedPersonID.

What code should I use to get the PersonID for the user on the form?   Or can I just use a simple XSLT select to find that data? I.e. `<xsl:value-of select="…"/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The qbo.Security.Utilities.XsltExtension.cs class is made available to all QBO3 XSLTs using the "urn:qbo3-security" namespace.

In your XSLT, include this namespace in the declaration, such as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:security="urn:qbo3-security" ...>
```

and then you can use any of the extension methods, such as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="security:userID()"/> // PersonID; e.g. 128
<xsl:value-of select="security:hasPermission('SomeFunction')"/> // boolean
<xsl:value-of select="security:isInRole('Administrators')"/> // boolean
<xsl:value-of select="security:user()//LastLogin"/> // XML node of Person record
<xsl:value-of select="security:userName()"/> // Person; e.g. admin@quandis.com
<xsl:value-of select="security:getDefault('qbo.HomePage')"/> // URL of home page
<xsl:value-of select="security:contactName()"/> // Contact.Contact || Person.Person
```